# Apache choose folder based on url parameter and keep url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'd like to have a way to access folders on my server based on the name given in the url as a parameter.

Let's say my website is www.site.com

I'd like to access custom folders under the main directory by sending a parameter on the url but without having a redirect changing the url.

So I'd provide the folder in the parameter: www.site.com/dev1
This way people wouldn't have to remember the full url be aware of it.

my base folder as per the vhost is /var/www/developers
the subfolders are dev1, dev2, dev3 and so on.
Under dev1/2/3 there is a folder called Portal.

```
-/var/www/developers
--/var/www/developers/dev1
----/var/www/developers/dev1/Portal
------/var/www/developers/dev1/website/Portal
```

my current .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/website/Portal  -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /$1/website/Portal [L]
```

Whilst it is working, it keeps changing my url to `www.site.com/dev1/Portal`

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because `mod_dir` is adding a trailing slash after directory `portal`.

Have your rule like this by having a trailing slash in your rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/website/Portal -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1/website/Portal/ [L]
```